# qemu-img command doesn't create the qcow2 file

Tags: qemu, macos, iso, qcow2

I am using a macOS 12.2.1 with m1 chip. I successfully installed qemu using brew. I am trying to convert my ubuntu iso file to qcow2. When I run,

> qemu-img create -f qcow2 ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-arm64.iso 20G

I get the output,

> Formatting 'ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-arm64.iso', fmt=qcow2 cluster_size=65536 extended_l2=off compression_type=zlib size=21474836480 lazy_refcounts=off refcount_bits=16

which is pretty right, I guess, but it doesn't create the qcow2 file, cause when I run 'ls' it gives

> ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-arm64.iso

What have I done wrong? Please help.

Comment: It does create a new blank qcow2 disk image file called `ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-arm64.iso` of 20G in size as you specified. There is no need to convert an ISO to qcow2. I don't understand what the goal is.

Comment: For qemu virtualisation, qcow2 is better than iso, and if it's a qcow2 file, then the extension wouldn't be .iso.